# Prevent Angular ng-repeat on page load

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat loop set up on my page that initially I don't need anything done with until an action is called (I get some $http data returned and the ng-repeat loop populates content there).  The issue is that in page load the console is throwing me an error because it doesn't have any data on page load to do anything with in that loop.  Should I just disregard the error because everything still works fine or is there an action I can take to prevent this error on initial page load?

Comment: You could initialize your data as an empty array at the beginning of your script. It won't prevent the ng-repeat loop, but there is a chance it will prevent the error you have on page load.

Comment: you can add `ng-if` to the `<div>` with `ng-repeat` so that it the expression of `ng-if` only resolves to `true` if there is data to display in `ng-repeat`

Comment: As  @Gurbakhshish Singh mentioned, add ng-if. With something like this ng-if="(!angular.isUndefined(arrayVariable) && (arrayVariable !== null) && (arrayVariable.length >0))"

Comment: It would much easier to give the proper solution if you posted the code, and the error. An ng-if is normally not necessary, and angular expressions normally don't throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize whatever you variable is in the ng-repeat as an empty array.

```
$scope.myArr = [];
```

When your async data comes back, assign it to the variable. That should prevent your errors.

```
$http.get(url)
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.myArr = data;
});

<li ng-repeat="item in myArr"></li> // or whatever you have on the dom
```